# How to get access to application context from the thread that was created via Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await, c#-5.0, applicationcontext

I have a method that is ran in the main application thread, but creates new `Task` for long-running operation and `await`s it's result.

```
public async Task<CalculatorOutputModel> CalculateXml(CalculatorInputModel input)
{
    // 1
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(
        new Func<CalculatorOutputModel> (() => 
        {
            // 2
            using (var ms = Serializer.Serialize(input))
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                using (var rawResult = Channel.RawGetFrbXmlOutputs(ms)) // 3
                {
                    var result = Parser.Parse(rawResult);
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }),
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

My problem is that the AppContext in points (1) and (2) are "a bit" different. In point 1 there is usual application context in `Current` property, that has all the data I need. In point 2, as you understand, there is `null` reference in `AppContext.Current`, so I can't access any data. The problem with accessing context in point 2 seems to be easy, just "catch" current context in local variable or pass it as the parameter. The problem for me is  more difficult because I need to access the context somewhere in the deep of line marked as "3".
The class itself is derived from `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>` and the place where I need to get access to the context is the class that implements `IClientMessageInspector`.

```
class CalculatorMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        if (AppContext.Current != null)
        {
            // never goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Just to clarify, here is the call stack (I can't pass my context inside required method):
[image: Call stack]

So:

1. I can't pass context to `Channel`'s method because it does not make any sense;
2. I can't save required parameters from context in `Channel` because it is proxy class;
3. I can't save required parameters in `CalculatorMessageInspector` because it is created within the place where current context is already null.

Can anyone advise any method how can I stay within the same context in another thread? Or, at least, how can I pass parameter from the place marked "2" inside the methods hierarchy? Maybe, I can use `SynchronizationContext` somehow to achieve it? Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

**Update**

`AppContext.Current` consider to be the same as `HttpContext.Current != null ? HttpContext.Current.Items[AppContextKey] : null`

**Update 2**
So it seems, that in this case there is no common solution to persist the context. Hence, the only applicable solution in this concrete situation (that is quite specific) is to capture required parameters using closure and save then in an object, that will be available in required method (for me worked adding properties to the implementator of `IEndpointBehavior`, but that solution is a bit odd). Thereby, the most applicable solution is to throw away the asynchronous wrapping over the sync call, so the `AppContext` never "goes away". Mark Stephen's answer as the right then.

Comment: You can't pass context, but can you change the method signature? If you can, then you can pass a delegate to BeforeSendRequest() and then execute some code in that delegate from a block of code that has access to the current AppContext.

Comment: What is `AppContext`?

Comment: Just a comment, you should be using `Task.Run` with `async-await` like Stephen explains here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: @DavidKhaykin I can't change BeforeSendRequest signature because this is the member of [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. So, unfortunately, this is not the case. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @StephenCleary That's nice point, that I missed. `AppContext.Current` is the static `get`-ter of our internal class, but looking into sources showed that in described case this is equivalent to `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items[AppContextKey]`. So it is able to replace `AppContext.Current` with `HttpContext.Current` in my question.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Thanks for the tip. I tried to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` because thought that using `SynchronizationContext` would bring me closer to my target :)

Comment: @Eadel Indeed. But as the article states, `Task.Run` was tailored to e used with `async-await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `async` and `await` on ASP.NET, you must target .NET 4.5 and turn off quirks mode. The best way to do this is to set `/configuration/system.web/httpRuntime@targetFramework="4.5"` in your web.config.

Also, you shouldn't use `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` on ASP.NET. So your code should look more like this:

```
public CalculatorOutputModel CalculateXml(CalculatorInputModel input)
{
    using (var ms = Serializer.Serialize(input))
    {
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (var rawResult = Channel.RawGetFrbXmlOutputs(ms))
        {
            var result = Parser.Parse(rawResult);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly how my code used to look like some time ago. But in that case the code block in `using` statement will hang the thread for some seconds, because a call to the this channel is quite time consuming. That was the main reason why I decided to perform this actions in another thread. In my example, it is expected, that main thread, that calls this method, continues preparation of other requests and making them meanwhile. Am I missing something?

Comment: First, ASP.NET is naturally multithreaded. So unless your code is doing something really weird, other requests can be handled by other threads. Secondly, if you want to use `async`/`await`, then you'll want to call the actual channel asynchronously, not wrap a synchronous call in another thread. I.e., if `Channel` is a WCF proxy, you could change your `using` statement to `using (var rawResult = await Channel.RawGetFrbXmlOutputsAsync(ms))`.

Comment: @Eadel read this (http://curah.microsoft.com/44400/async-and-aspnet) to see how threading works in ASP.NET and how it works with `async-await`.